# Ubuntu 12.04: Random freezes

Tags: ubuntu

I get random freezes with Ubuntu 12.04 (kernel 3.2.0-31). The entire system freezes, mouse pointer doesn't move, keyboard input doesn't work. I'd say this happens about once per week on a system that is up 24/7. A hard reboot solves the problem.

My questions: (1) Has anyone else experienced this? (2) I have a suspicion that a kernel upgrade may solve this. How much of a pain in the ass is it to upgrade an Ubuntu kernel, and how much will I break things like apt-get if I do upgrade the kernel myself?

Comment: kern.log and syslog contain nothing that helps, btw.

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but experienced exactly same issue with Ubuntu 11.04 with kernel version 2.6.38-14-generic.

Comment: Are you running server or a workstation?  If Workstation can you post `/var/log/X.0.log`?

Comment: Looks like GPU hang?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, on some more often (laptop), on some sometimes (desktop with new components), on some never (server hardware or quality desktop with a bit older components).
2. Download kernel deb from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ which you like, install it with `dpkg -i kernel_name.deb` and reboot. If it is not better, install some other version and reboot again. If no new kernel shows more stable then default - then you know that kernel is not an issue, reboot to default kernel and uninstall all new kernels you tried. That way, you still have your default Ubuntu install without much sweat (except for a few downloads & reboots).

And yes, almost all my Linux PC's are up 24/7, so I know - every system freeze annoys me. :) Full freezes are extremely rare, most often (if something freezes) GNOME freezes but I can ping and ssh to PC, so usually just X session restart is enough.